# How to output characters of my language to HTML file in C++ correctly?

Tags: html, c++

I try to output a wstring variable that contains unicode characters to an HTML file but the problem is that when I open the file via web browser, it shows me strange similar characters instead of unicode ones (ANSI charecters are shown correctly). However if I open the file via text editor (for example notepad), it is shown totally correclty. Besides I need to output certain currency character but it interrupts all of the following output (of course it is not outputed itself). Obviously, this problem appears only with C++ output: if I write something to HTML file manually, everything is shown by browser correctly.

I have been searching some discussions about that problem and all of them advice to use different variaties of setting locale but it works only with console output not with file one. They also advice to set the "UTF-8 with BOM" encoding but it does not work too.

Here is some examples of my app's behaviour.

Here is the HTML code which I output with C++:

```
<div class="table-head">
    <div>Type</div>
    <div>Name</div>
</div>

<div class="table-row">
    <div>Системные устройства</div>
    <div>Диспетчер томов</div>
</div>
```

And here is what is shown by browser:

Type Name

��������� ���������� ��������� �����

And the second example related to a currency character: here is another part of HTML file without this character:

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div>Date Format</div>
    <div>d MMMM yyyy &apos;г.&apos;</div>
</div>

<div class="table-row">
    <div>Time Format Specifier</div>
    <div>24-hour format</div>
</div>
```

Browser's output:

Date Format             d MMMM yyyy '�.'

Time Format Specifier   24-hour format

As you can see there is a character of my language "г" and it is still outputed incorrecly. But back to the example: let us add a new container to HTML file (of course with C++ i/o code) which is similar to two other ones and which contains the currency character "₽". Here is the result:

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div>Date Format</div>
    <div>d MMMM yyyy &apos;г.&apos;</div>
</div>

<div class="table-row">
    <div>Currency</div>
    <div>
```

And this is the end of the file, e.g. the rest data that had to be outputed was lost because it was interrupted by currency character. You can guess what browser outputs as a result.

I am showing specific example of how I get "Date Format" value from the previous example and how I output it. Here is the getting of it:

```
#include <Windows.h>

...

TCHAR temp[STRINGSIZE];
constexpr int length = STRINGSIZE;

GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SLONGDATE, temp, length);
_tcscpy_s(m_SysInfoStruct.m_strDateFormat, temp);

...
```

Where m_SysInfoStruct.m_strDateFormat has TCHAR[] type.

And here is the output process:

```
#include <Windows.h>

...
#ifdef UNICODE
    #define tofstream std::wofstream
#else
    #define tofstream std::ofstream
#endif
...
using tstring = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;
...

tofstream outputFile("somehtmlfile.html");
outputFile << getHTMLReport();
outputFile.close();

...
```

The following one occurs in getHTMLReport():

```
...

tstring czTemp(_T(""));

czTemp.append(_T("<"));
czTemp.append(_T("div"));
czTemp.append(_T(">"));
czTemp.append(m_SysInfoStruct.m_strDateFormat);
czTemp.append(_T("</"));
czTemp.append(_T("div"));
czTemp.append(_T(">\n"));

m_sHTMLData += czTemp;

...

return m_sHTMLData;
```

It is more or less like this.

Comment: The short (but not so useful answer) is: use UTF-8 everywhere. You will need to convert your `std::wstring` to a regular `std::string` with UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Your HTML is missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` and missing the `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.  You probably should be using UTF-8 instead of whatever encoding is being used in your `wstring`.

Comment: Botje, it is neccessary to use wstring but more precisly to use tstrng that is defined as std::basic_string<TCHAR> (I have UNICODE macro defined).

Comment: Eljay, no, <!DOCTYPE html> and <meta charset="UTF-8"> are not missed.

Comment: can you post the C++ that output the unicode chars? the problem should be the export charset doesn't matches the html charset

Comment: Code Rage, sure. I have added some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::wofstream` provides UTF16 interface, and it is a headache in many ways.

You want UTF8 interface using `std::ofstream`. If you are doing this in Windows, then you most likely get UTF16 input from Windows I/O functions. You want to convert UTF16 to UTF8, and write to `std::ofstream`. You might consider avoiding those `T` macros as they tend to only complicate things.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <io.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <windows.h>

std::string get_utf8(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    if(wstr.empty()) return std::string();
    int sz = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::string res(sz, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], -1, &res[0], sz, 0, 0);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring html = L"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>";
    html += L"Системные устройства";
    html += L"</html></body>";

    std::string utf8 = get_utf8(html);

    std::ofstream outputFile("test.html");
    outputFile << utf8;
    outputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for "avoid those T macros".  They are useful for MS who write libraries that need to be consumable by both ASCII and UTF-16 applications; they are not useful for applications that just use UTF-16 to communicate with Windows.